# Jenkins pipeline maven wrapper call throws java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that simply does this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                 sh "./mvnw -version"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is it throws an exception: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`. Any idea how I can fix or troubleshoot it?

```
Running shell script
+ ./mvnw -version
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
```

Comment: maybe you have no internet connection on your server?

Comment: I am using a Jenkins server managed by other team and, that's what was happening. Thanks.